# Pattern tile shape. Artboard size

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am a starter in illustrator. I make pattern and put it in swatches panel. When I open it from swatches panel, the pattern tile has a **rectangle** shape even if I have given the size of a **square** at first (before drawing and making pattern). 1) How can I have a square pattern tile not rectangle? after that, 2) How can I make a new  artboard of my pattern tile?(When I open my rectangle(!!!) pattern tile from swatches panel, and draw a new square by ellipse tool to drag the tile to it,suddenly all the screen is my pattern tile!)(There is no new white square to see and drag to it)
Can anybody help me solve the problemsa? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A patter tile, in almost all instances, has *no* correlation to artboard size.

You can change the "tile" aspect of a patter in **Pattern Editing Mode** by clicking the `Tile edit` button on the **Pattern Editor Panel**. This allows you t alter the aspect of the tile shape.

[image]

If you want a *square* tile, then you need to ensure the `Tile Type` is set to `Grid`. Any other setting will result in a non-square shape. i.e. "Brick" results in rectangles, "Hex" in hexagons.

[image]

<sub>Panel may look different in CC 2020, but it should still be relatively the same in function.</sub>

---

To fill an artboard with a pattern, *draw a rectangle* on the artboard and then click the pattern swatch in the **Swatches Panel** to apply the pattern fill. It's the *same procedure* you'd use to fill a rectangle with color. The only difference is the swatch you click. You do *not* want to be in Pattern Editing Mode when filling the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. I chose Grid and I had a square. But I still have problem with my pattern tile coloring. I go Window > Pattern Options > Make Pattern. Then I click on Fill swatch, I draw a rectangle by the Elipse Tool (on selecting square or rectangle which is around my first drawing, in the middle of the pattern) as my background. 1) This background is like a gride. There is a square or rectangle around the basic drawing which I made pattern tile with. Even if I send it to back.

Comment: Sorry, even for dotted pattern, suppose green circles are in the middle of yellow squares and there is a white stroke around each yellow square!!! But I need just a yellow background without any grid. What is my mistake? Thanks.